# qBittorrent problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qbittorrent

I upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 yesterday. After that, when I launch qBittorrent, I got this message:

```
You updated from an older version that saved things differently.
You must migrate to the new saving system. If you continue, you
will not be able to use an older version than v3.3.0 again.
--- Abort/OK
```

What does that mean and what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give the results of this: `find $HOME -iname  qBittorrent-resume.ini`

Comment: @andrew.46 No result. Just jump to the next command prompt.

Comment: I can see references to this bug online with varied solutions but looks like newest versions have fixed the issue. I shall post upgrade instructions and this should get around the issue as well as give you the shiniest and best :)

Comment: Mind you unless I have misunderstood: You have the option to press OK and simply move forward with the new saving arrangement?

Comment: Yes, I can press OK.

Comment: OK then you should be right to go :). Consider 'accepting' my answer below which incorporates using the new file saving as well as giving advice to upgrading version if the transition to the new arrangements fails...

Comment: @andrew.46 So you mean I can simply choose "OK" and everything will be fine?

Comment: That certainly is my understanding, the fuss is that you cannot easily return to the file saving used by older versions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new file saving arrangement in place for the Xenial version of `qBittorrent` that you should *accept* by selecting 'OK'. On some occasions the transition has *not* been working and this is a bug that can then be bypassed by upgrading your version of `qBittorrent` (this bug having been fixed in the neweste version).

Upgrade your copy to the latest version of `qBittorrent` by using a PPA that is owned by one of the `qBittorrent` developers. Run the following from within a Terminal screen:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

Then open and close Dash, and again open Dash and you should now see the very latest `qBittorrent` (3.3.5) with the bug no longer present:

[image]

Then you will always have the newest stable version from the developer's own PPA. An added bonus with using this PPA is that you will now easily be able to get the latest version of `qBittorrent` as soon as it is released by the developers and then placed on this PPA...

References:

- [qBittorent: Warning of file saving changes...](https://qbforums.shiki.hu/index.php/topic,3684.msg20137.html#msg20137)

Comment: `qbittorrent is already the newest version (3.3.1-1)` should i remove qb before install ?